# Furnace won't start

Tags: hvac

I have a Goodman two-stage furnace that won't start. Model # GMV950905DXA

It was running two days ago and then stopped. Outdoor temperature is now -20 and will drop to -34 tonight. LP in tank is at 65%. It won't even start the blower or flames. The thermostat is good and there is 120V power to the furnace and the 24V transformer has the proper output.

Does anyone have any ideas??

Comment: Is the control board throwing any codes?

Answer (score 1):

This is a high efficiency furnace not a boiler and no pilot. It uses a glow plug. You have to turn of power. open the top door. Turn on power. See if exhaust motor runs. Then see if glow plug runs. Then see if gas valve opens.

Answer (score 0):

On gas furnaces (Nat. gas and propane) its usually the thermocouple that fails or the pilot light has simply been blown out (usually from a down draft). Nothing else will get power until and unless the gas portion (pilot, gas pressure, working thermocouple, open valve, etc.) is working normally. Check first for a pilot flame and follow the posted instructions for re-ligting, if it has gone out. If it is not a pilot problem it could mean the thermocouple is not sending the signal to the gas control valve and may need replacing. Thermocouples are commonly replaced items, not very expnsive and found in any hardware store.

Comment: The OP's furnace has neither a thermocouple nor a standing pilot, according to the manuals I've been able to find for it...

Answer (score 0):

Some boilers won't start if the water system is not pressurized...

There is usually a flexible loop and ball valves to do this and a gauge with a "green" section roughly 1 to 1.5 bar...

Hopefully the OP has already got this sorted though, just posting for information.